# Using Pyspark, Ipython in AWS, how to suppress constant output stream?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, ipython, pyspark

I've launched pyspark in ipython in an AWS ec2 instance via:

```
IPYTHON=1 ./spark/bin/pyspark
```

Ipython launches, and things seem to work. However, now whats happening is I'm getting this constant feedback stream even when I haven't done anything:

```
15/02/19 23:47:34 INFO client.AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app- 
20150219234524-0001/46 is now LOADING
15/02/19 23:47:34 INFO client.AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-   
20150219234524-0001/38 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
15/02/19 23:47:34 INFO cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor app-
20150219234524-0001/38 removed: Command exited with code 1
15/02/19 23:47:34 ERROR cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asked to remove 
non-existent executor 38
15/02/19 23:47:34 INFO client.AppClient$ClientActor: Executor added: app-
20150219234524-0001/47 on worker-20150219205401-ip-172-31-57-   
73.ec2.internal-40221 (ip-172-31-57-73.ec2.internal:40221) with 4 cores
15/02/19 23:47:34 INFO cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor 
ID app-20150219234524-0001/47 on hostPort ip-172-31-57-73.ec2.internal:40221 
with 4 cores, 12.7 GB RAM
```

I can still run commands. Simply pressing enter a few times brings up a command line. However, massive amounts of text constantly scrolling by makes things difficult. Is there any way to suppress this feedback?

Answer (score 0):

Two ways of doing this:

- set the log4j level to `OFF`, the easiest way to do this is by setting it in your `spark-defaults.conf` e.g:

`spark.driver.extraJavaOptions         -Dspark.driver.log.level=OFF`

- pipe it to /dev/null or what is probably a better idea a file in the usual manner.

The former you can probably set via the command line too.